# Global Variables vs. Config Variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have custom config items in application/config/config.php.

Samples of my custom config items:

```
$config['website_title'] = 'ABC Website'; //Assume website title is fixed
.
.
.
etc
```

Now i can call `$this->config->item('website_title')` any where in my application. However, i don't find it efficient enough because i might have multiple $this->config->item('website_title') within the project. I came up with the following solution:

1.Create a function, within a helper, that return the config item as the following:

```
public function website_title() {

  return $this->config->item('website_title');

}
```

2.Now i can call website_title() as many as i want.

**Is this a good solution? Do you see any downsides?**

> Note: I try to avoid using global variables because i tried it and i
>   faced many unnecessary problems such as undefined variables,
>   surprised!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "efficient"?  Runtime efficiency? Coding efficiency? Clarity?

In terms of runtime efficiency [Truth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/truth)'s suggestion of using is perhaps the simplest and best.  However, I prefer to code using a strict class/object implementation, and in reality defines are just global constants.

If you profile the vast majority of scripts, you will find that however you code your configuration referencing makes an immaterial impact on runtime, so I would suggest going for simplicity and clarity of coding every time.

One approach is to use a singleton class (there are lots of tutorials on doing this) and use the magic method `__get()` to allow you to dynamically overload parameter access.  This is one case where I feel that you have to use a single class as these property methods only work with object (non-static) parameter references.  Hence you can simply use:

```
$cfg = Configuration::get();
...
...   $cfg->someConfigParam ...    // to refer to a config parameter
...
...   /* or even */ ... Configuration::get()->someOtherParameter ...
```

Note that `$cfg` in the above example essentially stores an object handle, so there is no material runtime cost in doing this, and you can put this statement at the top of each function or class constructor that references a config item if you don't want to litter your code with `Configuration::get()->someOtherParameter` type calls.

The `Configuration::__get()` access function , plus the class constructor can handle all the complexities of caching and access of the individual parameters.  This also means that you con also encapsulate the source of the configuration: some application-specific D/B config table; one or more config files, ...; even cookies or URI parameters (so long as you include appropriate validation).

I personally don't recommend over loading with the `__set()` magic method as, IMO, overriding or setting a config parameter should be an explicit action, e.g. `$cfg->setConfigItem( 'someValue', TRUE );`

[Here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/docs/html/Economy.html#econcxt) is a link to the documentation on my config class if you want some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this sort of question on programmers once. I got a very good answer, simply use constants.

I.e. `WEBSITE_TITLE`